# account folder does not show asp.net core web app project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have created a project with asp.net core web app with individual authentication now I want to edit the registeration page but I cant find it. In the documentation page say go to /Areas/Identity/Pages/Account/RegisterConfirmation.cshtml.cs.

However, I cant find the account folder inside my Pages folder

so what do you think I have done wrong with project?

Thanks

Comment: Hello Huda was the answer helpful? Do you still need any assistance on this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to add `Identity` into your code. You would need to [scaffold identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) before you could see those codes. In summary, you would need to:

1. Create the project
2. Scaffold identity
3. Configure email sender (if any)

The [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0) is actually pretty straightforward and easy to follow.

Answer (score 0):

***`"I cant find the account folder inside my Pages folder":`***

[image]

> I think you are searching this URL
> `https://localhost:44374/Identity/Account/Register` into your project
> folder and finally you got to see below page: and there is no `Register` page

[image]

***`"So what do you think I have done wrong with project?":`***

> No you haven't done anything worng with the project at all. While we
> create the proejct with enabling the `individual authentication` it
> doesn't create any `Register` page within the project as its build in
> with the `SDK` which is not visiable in the project directory
> `Areas\Identity\Pages\` You can see the `DLL` files as below location.

[image]

> ***`Note:`*** If you want to get that `source code files` then you can get from our [official repository here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Identity/samples/IdentitySample.DefaultUI/Areas/Identity/Pages/Account). If you want to customize your identity then you can follow the [guideline here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Hope above steps guided you accordingly.